# Carry format from first to second page of TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting

I'm migrating a book from pdfLaTeX to LuaLaTeX and have a bit of a
problem with the table of contents

\newpage
\setlength{\cftbeforechapskip}{2.5em} %
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
\vspace{-1em}
\tableofcontents
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
\linespread{1}

The first page of the TOC has intended line separation of 2.5em.
However, the second page shows up with a line separation of 1em.

How do I carry the formating of the first page over to the second
page of TOC?

I tried appending  this line, but it had no effect

\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\cftbeforechapskip}{2.5em}

Comment: Please always post full but minimal examples. These sniplets are worthless when we do not know the context.

Comment: I apologize for the blunder encountered when I simply pasted from one document to another.